# Error add object in table contaning FK

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

I create tow table in sql server 2008 with relationship 1 - * .

```
table 1: Tour (ID, date, ..) : ID : PK
table 2 : Position (ID,..) : ID : PK, and TourID : FK
```

---

```
Tour tour = new Tour() { ID = 17 /* this ID exist in table tou*/};
Position position = new Position();
position.Tour = tour;
position.Longitude = Longitude;
position.DateHeurePosition = DateH;
db.AttachTo("Tour", tour);
db.AddToPosition(position);
db.SaveChanges();
```

this error is displayed:

> *An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager.
>   The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key*

How to resolve this error?

Comment: Have you tried setting `position.ID` to be a unique value?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Updating?

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve this error, you need to make sure that the id that you are adding is unique.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is that you created a new `Tour` with an ID that already exists.

In case you want to attach the position to the tour having ID=17, you have to get the record you want from the database:

Replace `position.Tour = tour;`
with `position.Tour = db.Tour.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.ID==17);`

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by detaching it first, there are some things you can do to Update the object by just setting the new values. Like this:

```
ObjectContext API: context.YourEntitySet.ApplyCurrentValues(newEntity);
DbContext API: context.Entry(oldEntity).CurrentValues.SetValues(newEntity);
```

I think the only thing you need here, is to find the attached item something like below

```
Tour t = Tours.Find(Id);//e.g. Id = 17 where Tours is the DbContext.Set<Tour>
position.Tour = t;
```

If you have another list of tours:

```
Tour t = Tours.First(i=> i.Id == Id);//e.g. Id = 17 where Tours is something with interface IEnumarable<Tour>
position.Tour = t;
```

And then set the values to the rest of that item.

But if you want to see a more complex implementation of update, here is my implementation of the update method:

```
public virtual void Update(T entity)
{
    DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DbContext.Entry(entity);
    var attachedEntity = DbSet.Find(entity.Id);

    if (attachedEntity != null)
    {
        var attachedEntry = DbContext.Entry(attachedEntity);

        entity.Created = attachedEntity.Created;
        entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;

        attachedEntry.CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        entity.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

When you adjust it to your needs, you can pass the object to the method and then save the changes.

Comment: Well, what part do you need to have explained? I would go with the (.Find) solution, the problem you are having is you are making a new item, while you should find the existing item and then edit that one.